# Find the rank of $A$ for all real $\lambda$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
   {7 - \lambda } & { - 12} & 6  \\
   {10} & { - 19 - \lambda } & {10}  \\
   {12} & { - 24} & {13 - \lambda }  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

> Find $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.rank(A)$

First, I've noticed that if $\lambda=1$ then there are two dependent columns.
Hence, when $\lambda=1$, $rank(A)=2$.

Now, what about $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{1\}$?
It's seems to me that the rank is $3$ when $\lambda \ne 1$, but how can I show it rigorously? Row reduction seems like a bad idea here.

### EDIT:

is it possible solving it without using eigenvalues?

Comment: You have a matrix that looks like $B-\lambda I_3$. Could you use that to your advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Gauss elimination technique to get

> $$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 7-\lambda&-12&6\\ 0 & -{
> \frac {{\lambda}^{2}+12\,\lambda-13}{-7+\lambda}}&\,{\frac {10(
> \lambda-1)}{-7+\lambda}}\\ 0&0&-{\frac {{\lambda}^{2}-1
> }{\lambda+13}}\end {array} \right]. $$

Note that, $\lambda =7$ and $\lambda=-13$ are special cases, you need to work them out separately.

Comment: @serial-downvoter: What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix has the form $A = B -\lambda I$. The eigenvalues of the matrix B are $(1,1,-1)$. So if $\lambda = 1$ the rank is 1 because only one of the eigenvalues of A is nonzero. If $\lambda = -1$, the rank is 2 because 2 of the eigenvalues of A are nonzeros. And if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1,1\}$ then all the eigenvalues of A are nonzeros, A is invertible and the rank is equal to 3.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eigenvalues. Can you give an alternative explanation please?

Comment: I can think about it. All I can say for now is that if $\lambda =1$ the first and third columns are equal and the first column is the second column times -1/2 hence the rank is 1.